# I am getting issue while deleting an item from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I click on the close button which I am having inside my recycler item the app gets crashes and throwing error. My code is below:

```
public void remove(int position) {
    asset_type.remove(position);
    asset_count.remove(position);
    asset_value.remove(position);
    AssetDetailsActivity.assetValueId.remove(position);
    AssetDetailsActivity.assetCountId.remove(position);
    AssetDetailsActivity.assetTypeId.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);

}
```

My error log and I am having more than 2 items in my recycler view

```
2019-02-25 11:04:16.733 5036-5036/com.tachyloans E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tachyloans, PID: 5036
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.tachyloans.common.MyAdapter.remove(MyAdapter.java:62)
        at com.tachyloans.common.MyAdapter$2.onClick(MyAdapter.java:113)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6310)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24970)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: Whichever list you have on line 62 of MyAdapter is having only one value and you are trying to delete second value from it which doesnt exists.

Comment: Try to delete with `position-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're trying to delete some items with `List.remove(position)` sequentially. You're probably deleting the same item position with your following code:

```
asset_type.remove(position);
asset_count.remove(position);
asset_value.remove(position);
AssetDetailsActivity.assetValueId.remove(position);
AssetDetailsActivity.assetCountId.remove(position);
AssetDetailsActivity.assetTypeId.remove(position);
```

The source of the problem is usually because you forget that a **non-primitive data type** is always passed by reference, for example: a `List`.

In the following typical RecylerView adapter the List (`List<YourDatum> data`) is passed by reference:

```
public class YourAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ..

    private List<YourDatum> mData;

    public YourAdapter(List<YourDatum> data) {
        mData = data;
    }
}
```

and that we usually pass the List via the constructor with:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ArrayList<YourDatum> mData;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // ...

         // assuming that createInitializeData(10) will create 10 data
         mData = createInitializeData(10);

         // Now we're passing the data to adapter.
         YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(mData);
         ...
     }
}
```

So, both the `YourActivity.mData` and `YourAdapter.mData` are pointing to the same location. Hence, whenever you're removing the item from `YourActivity.mData` then `YourAdapter.mData` item is also removed.

Now, you only need to use the following code for your case:

```
asset_type.remove(position);
asset_count.remove(position);
asset_value.remove(position);

// the following is not needed because it's incorrect
// AssetDetailsActivity.assetValueId.remove(position);
// AssetDetailsActivity.assetCountId.remove(position);
// AssetDetailsActivity.assetTypeId.remove(position)
```